# URL redirection not working just on one app

Tags: lightning-apps

I have this code running on every single Lightning app inside Salesforce, the Url opening works on every single app but not one. what could be the reason for that?

Here is the code -

```
openKnowledgeArticle : function(component, event, helper) {
    var knowledgeArticleId = component.get("v.varKnowledgeArticleId");
    var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
    console.log(knowledgeArticleId);
    workspaceAPI.openSubtab({              
        url: '/lightning/r/Knowledge__kav/'+knowledgeArticleId+'/view',
        focus: true
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a workspace API and console app.

So you can add a catch statement and check what is the error message you are getting.

```
    workspaceAPI.openSubtab({
        url: '/lightning/r/Knowledge__kav/'+knowledgeArticleId+'/view',
        focus: true
    }).catch(error => {
       console.error(JSON.stringify(error));
    });
```

Second thing to check is there is not `parentTabId` passed in the method.
[Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_lightning_openSubtab.htm)

By default, it might be opening always inside a parent tab and it might be working fine, but in that one app, you may have this code in primary tab. There it might fail as this method needs a primary tab id.

Comment: The catch statement doesn't seem to be firing at all, but I see the console.log(knowledgeArticleId) firing

Comment: Check for workspaceApi value and also check is the logic getting called from Primary tab, SubTab or Utility?

Comment: On the specific app where I am having the issue this is the error message I am getting `openTab` is not currently supported in this application. There is a slight change in the design of that app, especially on how tabs are displayed at the top.

Comment: `openTab is not currently supported in this application.` this will come if its not a console based application. What application is that?

Comment: I guess I found the issue, will mark it as closed. Thanks @Nagendra